# When should I use the plural form 'fossil fuels' and when the singular form?

Tags: word-usage

When should I use the plural form 'fossil fuels' and when the singular form?

Isn't fuel uncountable? Why do we ever use its plural form?

Comment: You have given no examples, no context. The term “fossil fuels” relates to different **types** of fuel, all of which have have a prehistoric, biological origin: coal, oil, and natural gas. What is your source for the assertion that “fuel” in this sense is a mass noun?

Comment: @JeffMorrow I have no clear idea about that, so I asked here.

Comment: “Fuel” is one of those words such as “water” that is sometimes a mass noun and sometimes a countable noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fossil fuels* is like *fish*. If there are different *kinds*, then use the plural form.

- There are many *fish* in the trout hatchery.
- He caught *fishes* of many types, bass and trout and perch.
- The coal-fired generating plant used thousand of tonnes of *fossil fuel*.
- The well provides both petroleum and natural gas, both *fossil fuels*.

Comment: I agree about fuels, but not about fishes. _Fish_ can be a mass noun when it is a foodstuff (_I had some fish_) and in that use it can take a plural for kinds of fish (_We have three fishes on the table, salmon, cod, and plaice_). But outside of that, _fish_ is **not** a mass noun, it is a count noun that happens to have a plural which is the same as its singular (as well as another plural which is different). Myself I rarely use _fishes_ to refer to animals, I almost always say _fish_; but I doubt that anybody uses _fishes_ distinctively when they happen to be of different kinds.